# Categorical independent variable and binary dependent variable

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, binary-data, categorical-encoding

Which test can I use for analyzing the effect of a categorical independent variable, such as preoperative ASA score (1/2/3/4), on a binary dependent variable, such as postoperative complication (yes/no)?

I know that the chi squared test is an option, but this test does not tell me if the significant difference lies between ASA 1 and ASA 2 or between ASA 2 and ASA 3,...

Is there a statistical test I can use to know between which independent categories the significant difference is situated?

Answer (score 2):

You can use logistic regression with an ordinal predictor variable. By choosing the encoding system for the predictor, you can get the information presented in a useful form. Here [is a useful UCLA page](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/) overview for different categorical encoding systems, using R (there are similar pages for other languages.) For your purposes, maybe a successive differences coding is natural. Below I will simulate some data (using R) and present analysis, coding in different ways.

But first, similar questions have been asked before, see [Logistic regression? multiple categorical and ordinal values to predict binary outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280680/logistic-regression-multiple-categorical-and-ordinal-values-to-predict-binary-o),   [Encoding of categorical data/feature/predictor for binary classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366688/encoding-of-categorical-data-feature-predictor-for-binary-classification)

```r
set.seed(7*11*13)
ncats <- 5
k <- 100
ordvar <- factor(rep(1:ncats, each=k), ordered=TRUE)
Y  <- rbinom(ncats*k, 1, rep(seq.int(from=0.1, to=0.9, len=ncats), each=k)) 
ordnum <- rep(1:ncats, each=k)
mydf <- data.frame(Y, ordvar, ordnum)

mod.ordvar0 <- glm(Y  ~ ordvar, family=binomial, data=mydf)

mod.ordvar1 <- glm(Y  ~ ordvar, family=binomial, data=mydf, contrasts=list(ordvar=MASS::contr.sdif))

mod.ordnum <- glm(Y  ~ ordnum + I(ordnum^2), family=binomial, data=mydf)
```

The first model we estimated used R's standard encoding for ordinal predictors, which is orthogonal polynomials:

```r
 summary(mod.ordvar0)

Call:
glm(formula = Y ~ ordvar, family = binomial, data = mydf)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1945  -0.8782   0.4343   0.7585   2.0200  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.1435     0.1183   1.213    0.225    
ordvar.L      3.2513     0.3068  10.598   <2e-16 ***
ordvar.Q      0.1498     0.2805   0.534    0.593    
ordvar.C      0.1612     0.2465   0.654    0.513    
ordvar^4     -0.1442     0.2151  -0.670    0.503    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 692.35  on 499  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 514.22  on 495  degrees of freedom
AIC: 524.22
```

But I guess that often (and in your case ...) successive differences (comparing level $i+1$ with level $i$) is more informative:

```r
summary(mod.ordvar1)

Call:
glm(formula = Y ~ ordvar, family = binomial, data = mydf, contrasts = list(ordvar = MASS::contr.sdif))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1945  -0.8782   0.4343   0.7585   2.0200  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.1435     0.1183   1.213 0.225046    
ordvar2-1     1.1472     0.3666   3.130 0.001751 ** 
ordvar3-2     0.7138     0.2932   2.434 0.014920 *  
ordvar4-3     1.1386     0.3055   3.727 0.000194 ***
ordvar5-4     1.2150     0.4188   2.901 0.003716 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 692.35  on 499  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 514.22  on 495  degrees of freedom
AIC: 524.22
```

But note that these two models are equivalent, they give exactly the same fitted probabilities. In mathematical thers, the only difference is in the choice of a basis for a vector space. The last model is **not** equivalent, it is a reduced model, using the ordinal levels as numeric, and fitting only a linear+quadratic model, so two less parameters:

````r
summary(mod.ordnum)

Call:
glm(formula = Y ~ ordnum + I(ordnum^2), family = binomial, data = mydf)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1697  -0.8215   0.4468   0.7548   1.9728  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.58216    0.58633  -4.404 1.06e-05 ***
ordnum       0.74624    0.43060   1.733   0.0831 .  
I(ordnum^2)  0.04420    0.07192   0.615   0.5388    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 692.35  on 499  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 515.15  on 497  degrees of freedom
AIC: 521.15 ```
````