# ANOVA equivalent for proportional dependent variable?

Tags: r, anova, proportion

I want to test for significant differences in different years of a proportional variable in my data set. Essentially, I know I can do an ANOVA to show that there are significant differences between years in terms of temperature, however, I am also interested in carrying out the same test for one of my proportional variables (no. of successes/no. of trials). I came across Test of equal or given proportions `prop.test` [here](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/R/R6_CategoricalDataAnalysis/R6_CategoricalDataAnalysis6.html) but I am unsure if that is the right way to go, because in order to use this, I have to re-calculate the proportion variable, overall, for every year, as opposed to using the proportion data I have per station? Is this correct? Am I sacrificing some of the resolution I have by running this test? Or is there a repeated-measures version of some sort I should be using?

Comment: Look into logistic regression, search this site.

Comment: I considered that, however, it would show the overall trend in over the years, which is not what I am interested in, I want to show that there are significant differences between years?

Comment: Then you can code time as *ordinal*, look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503545/categorical-independent-variable-and-binary-dependent-variable/503571#503571